# Different results from new DateTime() and DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, datetime

I noticed some odd behaviour in a unit test for C#.

Given the following code:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015");
Assert.AreEqual(dateTime, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1));
```

I get a failed test with the result:

```
Expected: 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
But was:  01/01/2015 00:00:00 +00:00
```

I've tried calling `ToString()` on both, passing in `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and setting the DateKind on the new DateTime call to both Local and UTC but I get the same sort of results.

Why don't these two methods give the same result?

Comment: [using `==` the result it true](http://csharppad.com/gist/ba4918946a41c49b9c4c). must be something you're not showing.

Comment: What's your `CurrentCulture` ?

Comment: What's your testing framework, and what is the signature of `Assert.AreEqual` - does it take `Object`, `DateTime`, `String` or something else?

Comment: You should test with `Assert.AreEqual<DateTime>(actual, expected)`

Comment: Defo works in NUnit, but what are _you_ testing with? Could you add a tag

Comment: I'm using NUnit - Assert.AreEqual does not take a generic type, and the signature only allows for objects and numeric types.

Comment: @Amit I can confirm that == returns true, but Assert.AreEqual is false.

Comment: My guess it's dependent on the culture, DateTime.Parse can see it as 1 january 2015 or January 1st 2015 while new DateTime may see it differently

Comment: @DieVeenman not possible. DateTime is DateTime and there is no ambiguity. It's only the ToString that would produce a different results (potentiall issues could be with mixing date and month, but in this example it does not matter)

Comment: @rbm The Assert fail method is probably calling ToString() on the DateTime which returns a truncated, human-readable form of the date without the milliseconds component which is probably why Assert.AreEqual says it's not the same

Comment: Just to rule out other issues (referential equality for example), what happens with `Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1));`?

Comment: Still not possible, because if it's calling ToString() then it'd be calling ToString for _both_ arguments `Assert.AreEqual(dateTime, new DateTime(2015, 1, 1));` i.e. for `dateTime.ToString()` and the `(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)).ToString()`. *Unless* there is something really funny going on in NUnit and it calls ToString() differently, but i doubt this.

Comment: You can call `ToTicks()` for both dates and then compare it as a numeric value (they **must** be equal). But this is weird.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a shot with:

```
Assert.IsTrue(DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015"), new DateTime(2015, 1, 1) == 0);
```

Comment: While that may get around the problem, it doesn't really answer the question: _"Why don't these two methods give the same result?"_

Comment: Because it using AreEquals on a datetime may not use the proper comparator, but, as I'm not sure about it, I would prefer to get the feedback of the OP to explain more

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever hardcode dates as string. What is the point of doing it?

```
DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015")
```

instead do this:

```
new DateTime(2015,1,1)
```

DateTime.Parse is using your current culture by default to create a date. Consider following example:

```
DateTime.Parse("09/06/2015");
```

Is it 9th June or 6th September? Depending on your machine culture you will get different results. If your DateTime string comes from somewhere then you can force Parse method to use particular Format/Culture.

Going back to the question it's probably culture dependent.

Comment: _"What is the point of doing it?"_ Perhaps the unit test is simulating user input in a textbox?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - bang on. In reality, it's pulling values from a database table, but for a unit test I'm simulating that bit because unit tests.

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil you should specify culture for DateTime.Parse or list of supported formats to avoid confusion. Unit Tests should be deterministic

Comment: @Zbigniew When I did, I got the same results (described in the question).

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I can't test it now because I don't have NUnit installed but I assume underneath something like this happens:

(object)dateTime == (object)new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)

This is only a guess, have you tried to compare it with Assert.That(d1,Is.EqualTo(d2)) ?

Answer (score 0):

The question assumes in the simplified example that the first variable is a DateTime, when it is actually a DateTimeOffset. The public methods consumed that generated that variable had changed, and I presumed incorrectly that the return type was still a DateTime.

So the reason that they give different results is because they are different!

Lesson One: Check types even when you know what they are.
Lesson Two: Don't simplify too much in SO question examples.